# CSS - Prevent span from being wrapped around

Tags: html, css

I have a large database where post headers are tagged like this:

```
<h2><span>some number</span>some large text</h2>
```

When text of the header is too long, lines are wrapping below the span. I want to prevent this.

I'd need this:

```
<h2><span>some number</span>some large text</h2>
```

to behave like if it was this;

```
<h2><span>some number</span><span>some large text</span></h2>
```

but without re-tagging the posts because I have zillions of headers.

With CSS, so far my best has been adding padding to h2 and then negative margin to the span but the solution is not resposive and the wrapping around goes on. With White-space:no-wrap hte h2 lines won't break, no useful.

Comment: Can you post images of the current and desired output? Can you provide an example (including the CSS) of your current output as a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)? How would the second `<span>` change the behaviour of line wrapping? I am having trouble understanding your issue.